# prepareStatement(String) cannot find symbol

Tags: java, prepared-statement

Code is

```
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;
import java.beans.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.ResultSet;

    Connection Con = null;
    Statement St = null;
    ResultSet Rs = null;

private void AddMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
            
            
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            
            Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Inventorydb", "root", "root");
            
            java.sql.PreparedStatement add = Con.prepareStatement("Insert into Product Table values (?, ?, ?, ?");
            
            add.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ProductID.getText()));
            add.setString(2, ProductName.getText());
            add.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(ProductQuantity.getText()));
            add.setString(4, Brand.getSelectedItem().toString());
            int row = add.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product Successfully Added");
            Con.close();
            
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }



private static class DriverManager {

        private static Connection getConnection(String jdbcderbylocalhost1527Inventorydb, String root, String root0) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        public DriverManager() {
        }
    }
```

using Apache Netbeans IDE 15, specifically `java.sql.PreparedStatement add = Con.prepareStatement("Insert into Product Table values (?, ?, ?, ?");` this line, the `prepareStatement` is in red and says that "cannot find symbol" and for the life of me I cannot make sense as to why.

I've added the `Class.forName` first, then `java.sql` in `java.sql.Preparedstatement` second,

added a class `DriverManager`. Now the only error is `prepareStatement`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the program compile outside of NetBeans? --- "*I've added the `Class.forName` first ....*" - This only gets us the `class`-object for the specified class. The class has, however, to be on the  classpath. In the given case, it has no effect.

Comment: You imported the wrong `Connection`, you need to import `java.sql.Connection`, not `com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection`. Similary, you need to import `java.sql.Statement`, not `java.beans.Statement`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I have changed the imports into what Mark has said, and the error is gone now. Thank you both!

Comment: @jxseff Variable/field names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code:

Problem #1.

```
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;
import java.beans.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.ResultSet;
```

4 out of 5 of those imports are incorrect.  It looks like you have used your IDE's "suggest correction" feature, and it has suggested inappropriate imports.

This one is particularly harmful:

```
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;
```

That `Connection` class has nothing to do with JDBC and it doesn't have a `preparedStatement` method.  This is the cause of the "cannot find symbol" compilation error that you mentioned in the question title.

```
import java.beans.Statement;
```

This also nothing to do with JDBC ... but it doesn't look like you use it.

```
import org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.ResultSet;
```

These are JDBC related, but they are implementation classes for Derby NOT MySQL ... and you are apparently trying to use MySQL.  Even if you were using Derby, your code should be importing the `java.sql.*` versions of the classes.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

---

Problem #2.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

This is unnecessary.  You don't need to load the driver explicitly.  The `DriverManager.getConnection` call will load the driver class ... assuming that it is available.

---

Problem #3.

```
Con = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Inventorydb", "root", "root");
```

That JDBC URL is for Derby.  But in the previous line you are loading a MySQL driver!

---

Problem #4.

```
Con.prepareStatement("Insert into Product Table values (?, ?, ?, ?");
```

As noted in another answer, the SQL is incorrect.  You are missing a closing `)`.

---

Problem #5.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Product Successfully Added");
```

You are not checking the result from the `executeUpdate`, so that message could be a lie.

---

Problem #6.

```
Con.close();
```

Resource leak(s).

- You should also close the `PreparedStatement`.
- The `close()` calls should be made from a `finally` block`.  Or better still use *try with resources*.

If the try block doesn't complete, the `close()` at the end won't be called.  If that happens, the connection created at the start won't be closed.  You will eventually run out of database connections, and the application will fail.

---

Problem #7.

```
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Incorrect.  Only catch the exceptions that you *expect*.

---

Problem #8.

There are a number of serious style errors in your code.